# Why are some fingerprinted files in Jenkins defined as "outside Jenkins"

Tags: hudson, jenkins, fingerprint

I have several series of Jenkins jobs that are bound together along fingerprinted files.  When a file is fingerprinted, Jenkins will indicate which job originated the fingerprint, and that is used as a basis for the bindings, namely promotions.

But I've got one job that builds a fingerprintable file (nothing different from other jobs) and flags the file to be fingerprinted.  But when Jenkins shows the fingerprints for this job, the file is listed with an orign of "outside Jenkins".

The file was definitely first fingerprinted in Jenkins.  The job/build that did the first fingerprinting has not been deleted.  And this job is pretty much identical in function, plugin usage, and scripts to other jobs that work just fine.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: From what I have noticed in our builds, this could normally happen if this file is being created by a script that Jenkins does not know about, or possibly if you are not archiving this file. Does either case apply to you?

Comment: No - the file was created by the job, fingerprinted and archived - although archiving shouldn't be necessary.